# Why does GarbageCollector work like this?

Tags: garbage-collection, garbage

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println("total memory before "+runtime.totalMemory());
        System.out.println("free memory before "+runtime.freeMemory());
        for (int i=0;i < 1_000_000_000;i++){
            Date date = new Date();
            date=null;
        }
        System.out.println("total memory after "+runtime.totalMemory());
        System.out.println("free memory after "+runtime.freeMemory());
        System.gc();
        System.out.println("total memory after gc "+runtime.totalMemory());
        System.out.println("free memory after gc "+runtime.freeMemory());
    }
}
```

I wrote the code based on the tutorial video. The result of my output is as follows.

[This is the result on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqyKx.jpg)

[This is the result in the tutorial video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFnh7.jpg)

1)Why after calling gc () the total memory and free memory are VERY reduced?
2). And why isn't this happening in the tutorial video.

Comment: Different environment, different garbage collector implementation, different JIT compiler implementation, different initial memory setting.